# How to embed PyQtGraph in QML with a PySide2 Python Backend?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyqtgraph

Due to license restrictions I do not want to use QTCharts, so I am looking at [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) library.

I am working with PySide2 and QML. I am having difficulty getting a simple example working using QML because I don't know where to start. How do I embed one of these charts from the Python/Pyside2 backend to the QML front end?

Do I need to use a QQuickWidget somehow? Anyone have any examples of how to do this?

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyqtgraph is based on QGraphicsView which is part of the Qt Widgets submodule, so what you are asking for is equivalent to asking that a Qt Widget be embedded in QML and that is not possible. QQuickWidget does the opposite, ie embed a QML in a Qt Widget. In conclusion you can not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, having realized this I am planning on doing something different now.